# Unwanted padding in custom View with AutoresizeTextView on some devices

Tags: android, measurement

I solved my previous problem here:

[Can not set gravity with setGravity vertically programatically. Is this an android bug or feature?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821039/can-not-set-gravity-with-setgravity-vertically-programatically-is-this-an-andro)

Basically I have a custom Button with an AutoResizeTextView inside it. I want to animate the button and center the textview vertically. I solved it by Measuring and using the layout and onLayout methods. It works fine on most devices.

But on some devices there is an extra padding above the text inside AutoResizeTextView what I can not remove anyhow. The devices behaving badly are Kindle Fire and Samsung Galaxy Tab2 7. The layout is OK on Nook Color, on Motorola Xoom and on my Motorola Defy (CyanogenMod 10).

I created a sample project to demonstrate the problem. It includes 3 classes and a layout file:

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<herrbert74.artvsample.MyButton
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="46dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="54dp"
    android:text="Button" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Modified AutoResizeTextView.java:

```
package herrbert74.artvsample;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.text.Layout.Alignment;
import android.text.StaticLayout;
import android.text.TextPaint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
* Text view that auto adjusts text size to fit within the view. If the text
* size equals the minimum text size and still does not fit, append with an
* ellipsis.
* 
* @author Chase Colburn
* @since Apr 4, 2011
*/
public class AutoResizeTextView extends TextView {

// Minimum text size for this text view
public static final float MIN_TEXT_SIZE = 10;

// Interface for resize notifications
public interface OnTextResizeListener {
    public void onTextResize(TextView textView, float oldSize, float newSize);
}

// Off screen canvas for text size rendering
private static final Canvas sTextResizeCanvas = new Canvas();

// Our ellipse string
private static final String mEllipsis = "...";

// Registered resize listener
private OnTextResizeListener mTextResizeListener;

// Flag for text and/or size changes to force a resize
private boolean mNeedsResize = false;

// Text size that is set from code. This acts as a starting point for
// resizing
private float mTextSize;

// Temporary upper bounds on the starting text size
private float mMaxTextSize = 0;

// Lower bounds for text size
private float mMinTextSize = MIN_TEXT_SIZE;

// Text view line spacing multiplier
private float mSpacingMult = 1.0f;

// Text view additional line spacing
private float mSpacingAdd = 0.0f;

// Add ellipsis to text that overflows at the smallest text size
private boolean mAddEllipsis = true;

// Default constructor override
public AutoResizeTextView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

// Default constructor when inflating from XML file
public AutoResizeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

// Default constructor override
public AutoResizeTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    mTextSize = getTextSize();
}

/**
 * When text changes, set the force resize flag to true and reset the text
 * size.
 */
@Override
protected void onTextChanged(final CharSequence text, final int start,
        final int before, final int after) {
    mNeedsResize = true;
    // Since this view may be reused, it is good to reset the text size
    resetTextSize();
}

/**
 * If the text view size changed, set the force resize flag to true
 */
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    if (w != oldw || h != oldh) {
        mNeedsResize = true;
    }
}

/**
 * Register listener to receive resize notifications
 * 
 * @param listener
 */
public void setOnResizeListener(OnTextResizeListener listener) {
    mTextResizeListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Override the set text size to update our internal reference values
 */
@Override
public void setTextSize(float size) {
    super.setTextSize(size);
    mTextSize = getTextSize();

}

/**
 * Override the set text size to update our internal reference values
 */
@Override
public void setTextSize(int unit, float size) {
    super.setTextSize(unit, size);
    mTextSize = getTextSize();

}

/**
 * Override the set line spacing to update our internal reference values
 */
@Override
public void setLineSpacing(float add, float mult) {
    super.setLineSpacing(add, mult);
    mSpacingMult = mult;
    mSpacingAdd = add;
}

/**
 * Set the upper text size limit and invalidate the view
 * 
 * @param maxTextSize
 */
public void setMaxTextSize(float maxTextSize) {
    mMaxTextSize = maxTextSize;
    requestLayout();
    invalidate();
}

/**
 * Return upper text size limit
 * 
 * @return
 */
public float getMaxTextSize() {
    return mMaxTextSize;
}

/**
 * Set the lower text size limit and invalidate the view
 * 
 * @param minTextSize
 */
public void setMinTextSize(float minTextSize) {
    mMinTextSize = minTextSize;
    requestLayout();
    invalidate();
}

/**
 * Return lower text size limit
 * 
 * @return
 */
public float getMinTextSize() {
    return mMinTextSize;
}

/**
 * Set flag to add ellipsis to text that overflows at the smallest text size
 * 
 * @param addEllipsis
 */
public void setAddEllipsis(boolean addEllipsis) {
    mAddEllipsis = addEllipsis;
}

/**
 * Return flag to add ellipsis to text that overflows at the smallest text
 * size
 * 
 * @return
 */
public boolean getAddEllipsis() {
    return mAddEllipsis;
}

/**
 * Reset the text to the original size
 */
public void resetTextSize() {
    //ZBertalan:changed to mMaxTextSize
    super.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, mMaxTextSize);
    //ZBertalan:swapped them
    //mMaxTextSize = mTextSize;
    mTextSize = mMaxTextSize;
}

/**
 * Resize text after measuring ZBertalan: I commented this out because I
 * need to resize the text in onMeasure, to layout the textview based on
 * it's size
 */
/*
 * @Override protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int left, int top, int
 * right, int bottom) { if(changed || mNeedsResize) { int widthLimit =
 * (right - left) - getCompoundPaddingLeft() - getCompoundPaddingRight();
 * int heightLimit = (bottom - top) - getCompoundPaddingBottom() -
 * getCompoundPaddingTop(); //og.d("AnswerView", "inside ARTV.onLayout() " +
 * ); resizeText(widthLimit, heightLimit); } super.onLayout(changed, left,
 * top, right, bottom); }
 */

/**
 * @author zsbertalan Moved some code here to resize the textview here and
 *         position it based on it's new size
 */
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int newWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int newHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    resizeText(newWidth, newHeight);

    TextPaint p = getPaint();
    newHeight = getTextHeight(getText(), p, newWidth, getTextSize());

    this.setMeasuredDimension(newWidth, newHeight);
}

/**
 * Resize the text size with default width and height
 */
public void resizeText() {
    int heightLimit = getHeight() - getPaddingBottom() - getPaddingTop();
    int widthLimit = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    resizeText(widthLimit, heightLimit);
}

/**
 * Resize the text size with specified width and height
 * 
 * @param width
 * @param height
 */
public void resizeText(int width, int height) {
    CharSequence text = getText();
    // Do not resize if the view does not have dimensions or there is no
    // text
    if (text == null || text.length() == 0 || height <= 0 || width <= 0
            || mTextSize == 0) {
        return;
    }

    // Get the text view's paint object
    TextPaint textPaint = getPaint();

    // Store the current text size
    float oldTextSize = textPaint.getTextSize();
    // If there is a max text size set, use the lesser of that and the
    // default text size
    //ZBertalan: Bollocks. I changed to use mMaxTextSize all the time
    //float targetTextSize = mMaxTextSize > 0 ? Math.min(mTextSize, mMaxTextSize) : mTextSize;
    float targetTextSize = mMaxTextSize;

    // Get the required text height
    int textHeight = getTextHeight(text, textPaint, width, targetTextSize);

    // Until we either fit within our text view or we had reached our min
    // text size, incrementally try smaller sizes
    while (textHeight > height && targetTextSize > mMinTextSize) {
        targetTextSize = Math.max(targetTextSize - 2, mMinTextSize);
        textHeight = getTextHeight(text, textPaint, width, targetTextSize);
    }

    // If we had reached our minimum text size and still don't fit, append
    // an ellipsis
    if (mAddEllipsis && targetTextSize == mMinTextSize
            && textHeight > height) {
        // Draw using a static layout
        TextPaint paint = new TextPaint(textPaint);
        StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(text, paint, width,
                Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, mSpacingMult, mSpacingAdd, false);
        layout.draw(sTextResizeCanvas);
        int lastLine = layout.getLineForVertical(height) - 1;
        int start = layout.getLineStart(lastLine);
        int end = layout.getLineEnd(lastLine);
        float lineWidth = layout.getLineWidth(lastLine);
        float ellipseWidth = paint.measureText(mEllipsis);

        // Trim characters off until we have enough room to draw the
        // ellipsis
        while (width < lineWidth + ellipseWidth) {
            lineWidth = textPaint.measureText(text.subSequence(start,
                    --end + 1).toString());
        }
        setText(text.subSequence(0, end) + mEllipsis);

    }

    // Some devices try to auto adjust line spacing, so force default line
    // spacing
    // and invalidate the layout as a side effect
    // textPaint.setTextSize(targetTextSize);
    setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, targetTextSize);
    setLineSpacing(mSpacingAdd, mSpacingMult);

    // Notify the listener if registered
    if (mTextResizeListener != null) {
        mTextResizeListener.onTextResize(this, oldTextSize, targetTextSize);
    }

    // Reset force resize flag
    mNeedsResize = false;
}

// Set the text size of the text paint object and use a static layout to
// render text off screen before measuring
private int getTextHeight(CharSequence source, TextPaint originalPaint, int width,
        float textSize) {
    TextPaint paint = new TextPaint(originalPaint);
    // Update the text paint object
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    // Draw using a static layout
    StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(source, paint, width,
            Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, mSpacingMult, mSpacingAdd, true);
    layout.draw(sTextResizeCanvas);
    return layout.getHeight();
}

}
```

MyButton.java:
    package herrbert74.artvsample;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MyButton extends LinearLayout {
private AutoResizeTextView tv;
Context ctx;

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    AutoResizeTextView tv = (AutoResizeTextView) getChildAt(0);
    int padding = getHeight() / 8;
    int left = padding;
    int top = (getHeight() - tv.getMeasuredHeight()) / 2;
    int right = padding + tv.getMeasuredWidth();
    int bottom = getHeight() / 2 + tv.getMeasuredHeight() / 2;
    tv.layout(left, top, right, bottom);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    int w = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int h = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);

    if (w == 0) {
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        w = metrics.widthPixels;
        h = metrics.heightPixels;
    }
    tv.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(w - 40, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST),
            MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(h - 20, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST));
    setMeasuredDimension(MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec),
            MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec));
}

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
    tv = new AutoResizeTextView(context);
    tv.setMaxTextSize(54);
    tv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white));
    tv.setClickable(true);
    tv.setBackgroundResource(android.R.color.darker_gray);
    addView(tv);
}

public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs);
    ctx = context;
}

protected MyButton(Context context) {
    super(context, null);

}

public void setText(String text) {
    tv.setText(text);
}

public String getText() {
    return tv.getText().toString();
}

public void setTextSize(float f) {
    tv.setTextSize(f);
}
}
```

MainActivity.java:
    package herrbert74.artvsample;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
int x;
MyButton tv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    x = -1;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final String[] texts = { "normal text", "a bit longer text", "even longer text by a word", "Long. Longest text ever. Long. Long." };
    tv = (MyButton) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (x < texts.length - 1)
                x++;
            else
                x = 0;
            tv.setText(texts[x]);
            Log.d("AnswerView", "Text: " + texts[x]);
        }

    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

In the example project there is a button to change the text. At first there is no text, then the texts are getting longer. You can see the difference on the pictures.

The button backgrounds are black, the textview backgrounds are gray.

Here are the Defy textviews with correct buttons:

[image: Defy without text]
[image: First text]
[image: Second text]
[image: Third text]
[image: Fourth text]

Notice that on Kindle the textview already claims some place with no text!
Wrong layouts on Kindle Fire:

[image]
[image: First text]
[image: Second text]
[image: Third text]
[image: Fourth text]

In myButton constructor I tried the following of no avail:

```
tv.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
tv.setLineSpacing(0f, 1f);
tv.setCompoundDrawablePadding(0);
tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, null, null);
tv.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: We are currently having the same problem, with a S3 Galaxy